# Deleting all columns between the first one and the last four on a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet here with multiple columns full of data, ranging from cell AA to CT currently. The first column contains rows with headings and is frozen. Data is added to the end column of this range weekly. & Then all columns between the first and the last four are deleted (to show a month's worth of data but keep the headings intact).

I'm very new to VBA and I've been trying to write some code to automate this, so far I've managed to select the 5th column in from the end. But I can't get it to select the columns in between the 4th column from the end and Cell AA:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
     Dim i
     i = Range("KFIData").End(xlToRight).Offset(0,-4).EntireColumn.Select
     Columns("AA:ColumnFive").Delete
End Sub
```

Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete the **columns**? Or do you only want to delete the **content** of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you managed to catch column 5 from the end, use this statement:

```
Range(Columns("AA"), Columns(ColumnFiveFromEnd)).Delete
```

`ColumnFiveFromEnd` **can** be a number as well as a text identifier.

Comment: I think it would improve the readability, if you were consistent about addressing columns either by number og by letter(s). Otherwise it seems like a nice and simple line of code.

Comment: @Noceo I appreciate you concerns about readability. However in this case "AA" is more readable since it's related directly to the specification. the end column is a numeric variable and it's tough (though feasible) to convert it to text.

Comment: I agree that it is a minor concern. Your edit made it more understandable though. If he wasn't new to VBA, I probably wouldn't have addressed it at all :-)